# migration ":dependent" option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

in migration file, what is "**`:dependent`**" option used for, what could be the possible values for this option? And what does each value mean? Can anybody explain to me?

e.g. here it uses `:dependent => :delete`

```
def self.up
    create_table :car, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :brand_id, :null =>false
      t.timestamp :buy_at, :null => false

    end

    add_index :car, :brand_id
    add_foreign_key :car, :brands, :dependent => :delete
  end

 def self.down
     drop_table :balance_updated
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

In "normal" Rails, the `:dependent` option is used in the *model* like so:

```
has_many :models, :dependent => :destroy
```

However, I think you are using the [foreign_key_migrations](https://github.com/harukizaemon/redhillonrails/tree/master/foreign_key_migrations) plugin?
If so, take a look at [this source code line](https://github.com/harukizaemon/redhillonrails/blob/master/foreign_key_migrations/lib/red_hill_consulting/foreign_key_migrations/active_record/connection_adapters/table_definition.rb#L24) to know what the `:dependent` option is doing.

Answer (score 0):

> A FOREIGN KEY is a key used to link two tables together.
>
> A FOREIGN KEY is a field (or collection of fields) in one table that refers to the PRIMARY KEY in another table.
> [Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

So the car's column brand_id is depending on the (primary key) of the brand's table typically going to be called brand_id (default naming in sqlite3, if your using the default rails database).

So this ensures that if the brand is deleted i.e Mercedes from the Brand table then ALL cars that are branded as Mercedes in the Car table are also deleted.